# Unstable git status in Xcode 4.6 - manually refreshing alternates status between "modified" and "no changes"

Tags: xcode, macos, git

Under Xcode 4.6, the git status is acting in a very unstable manner. Here is an example after a new fresh commit (such that "git status" in the Terminal shows that there are no changes):

1. I modify a file, so "M" appears beside it in the sidebar.
2. I go to "File -> Source Control -> Refresh Status", then the "M" disappears!
3. I go to "File -> Source Control -> Refresh Status", then the "M" appears again!

Repeat steps 2 or 3 as necessary. Refreshing always alternatives between "M" and "no-M". What could possibly be causing this? Does anything come to mind?

Can I debug this somehow to track what could be going on?

I have tried deleting the entire DerivedData, clearing out the repositories in the Organizer, and restarting Xcode, but nothing is helping.

Comment: I can't find such phenomena in my Xcode. But, it can happen if modified file has just adding space or something. Git can find a meaning of code to some extent.

Comment: @akiniwa but that wouldn't explain the weird M and no-M alternating behavior...

Comment: Is this a local git? Are you storing it on DropBox or something similar?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 This is a local repository only. No DropBox, no online repositories, github, or whatever. Local only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, in my case, that this problem had something to do with the fact that I renamed a lot of files in my repository from "CamelCase" to "lowercase", including my project file and folder. This must have been improperly tracked somewhere somehow.

OS X uses a case-insensitive filesystem by default, whereas git is internally case-sensitive, and I believe the problem had something to do with this.

These are the steps I used to fix this. If you believe your problem may be due to changing the case of filenames, this may help you too.

1. Go to the root of your repository, and remove everything from it except for the .git folder using the "ls -la" (to see all the hidden files too) and "rm"/"rm -rf" commands.
2. Do a "git reset --hard" to get all your files back. You may now see that the case of your filenames have changed. In my case, in the root of my working copy, "myapp.xcodeproj" and "myapp" (folder containing all the code files) had changed to "MyApp.xcodeproj" and "MyApp" (folder). I thought I had changed it to lowercase, but apparently, this hadn't been tracked properly by git.
3. Now, rename your files to something unrelated. For instance, I renamed "MyApp.xcodeproj" to "foo.xcodeproj" and "MyApp" to "foo".
4. Then do "git add --all"
5. Now, rename your files to what you want. I renamed "foo.xcodeproj" to "myapp.xcodeproj" and "foo" to "myapp", which is how I wanted it to begin with (and what I thought I had already done).
6. Do another "git add --all".
7. Commit.

Now your life should be better and Xcode should behave well, because git is now seeing the exact same files (with the exact same case) as the Xcode project does.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has happened to me where I keep on committing and then the "M" disappears and few seconds later, it reappears and if I try to commit again, it allows me to commit again but with all the files showing zero changes. And then the M disappears and appears again.

The only way I found to fix this was oddly to insert a comment in your code and then commit. The M should disappear.